# Kubernetes Kubeadm single node, dashboard "malformed http response"

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm

I've just set up a single node Kubernetes cluster following the kubeadm guide to the letter. The cluster itself looks good, and all pods are running correctly:

```
will@kubemaster:~$ sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                        READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   calico-etcd-w6dkj                           1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   calico-node-mjsnr                           2/2       Running   0          16m
kube-system   calico-policy-controller-59fc4f7888-vc6x6   1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   etcd-kubemaster                             1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-kubemaster                   1/1       Running   1          16m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-kubemaster          1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   kube-dns-545bc4bfd4-mbbrl                   3/3       Running   0          16m
kube-system   kube-proxy-wkmlj                            1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubemaster                   1/1       Running   0          16m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-7f9dbb8685-rxwfw       1/1       Running   0          4m
```

I installed the dashboard using:

```
sudo kubectl create -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

I've tried serving up the kubrnetes dashboard locally by running "sudo kubectl proxy".

When I load "http://127.0.0.1:8001" I get the API endpoint listing, and all looks well. But when I add the /ui to load the dashboard (http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui), I get the following response:

```
Error: 'malformed HTTP response "\x15\x03\x01\x00\x02\x02"'
Trying to reach: 'http://192.167.141.3:8443/'
```

Also note, the above URL gets redirected to the API:

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard/proxy/
```

If I replace the HTTP with HTTPS, I get a "Secure connection failed, SSL recieved a record that exceeded the maximum permisslbe length".

If I try loading the dashboard without using the kubectl proxy, e.g. using the master IP, I get a connection refused.

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04, my kubectl version details are as follows:

```
will@kubemaster:~$ sudo kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"8", GitVersion:"v1.8.0", GitCommit:"6e937839ac04a38cac63e6a7a306c5d035fe7b0a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2017-09-28T22:57:57Z", GoVersion:"go1.8.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Since v1.7, Dashboard can only be accessed over HTTPS by default.

It is available at http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/ with `kubectl proxy`.

#### To deploy dashboard with HTTP (Not recommended for Production)

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Dashboard can be loaded at http://localhost:8001/ui with `kubectl proxy`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I couldn't find an answer after googling, so very much appreciated!

Comment: I was running into this problem with 1.11, thanks for the quick response!